# How to stream raw H.264 frames to Windows 10 UWP?

Tags: android, windows, uwp, raspberry-pi3, h.264

I want to know how to receive H.264 data stream and decoding it in UWP app. Any reference apps to this?

To add further information, I am using a H.264 camera with Raspberry Pi, and streaming data using TCP/IP. 
For reference on what I am trying to do, please find this [BLOG](http://frozen.ca/streaming-raw-h-264-from-a-raspberry-pi/)

Currently I was successful in streaming to an Android Application. My question is what are the Windows APIs alternatives to Android's [MediaCodec](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec) and [MediaFormat](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaFormat) libraries.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to know how to receive H.264 data stream and decoding it in UWP app. Any reference apps to this?

You sent stream data by TCP/IP, so you could use [Socket](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/networking/sockets) relevant APIs to get data in UWP.

Then, you could use ffmpeg library which supports decoding H.264 data in UWP. See https://github.com/Microsoft/FFmpegInterop

Please follow this [instructions](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/WinRT) to compile for UWP platform.

Comment: Thanks it was very helpful.I have another question. Is there a way to decode without using FFmpeg library? Like directly using H.264 decoders. Please share your inputs if it can be feasible to implement.

Comment: @shijuza I did not see any other ways.

Comment: Thanks @Xavier.  I was just trying to understand if it can be implemented using  the API's from Microsoft like MediaStreamSource class (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Media.Core.MediaStreamSource) and H.264 Video Decoder (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/medfound/h-264-video-decoder). Are there any sample applications which I can look upon to decode and render on the UWP side without using FFmpeg.

Comment: @shijuza No. You could not decode and render h.264 stream without FFmpeg.